# PHP construct function

Tags: php

Question: **Comparing those two paragraphs of code, why the first prints out nothing?**
When I used eclipse to run these code, nothing happened, I don't know why it does not print "the construct is running".

However, when I run second paragraph of code, which printed:
"The construct is running..."
"The Manager construct is running..."
**why?**

*First paragraph:*

```
<?php
class Employee 
{
    protected $name;
    protected $title;

    function _construct()
    {
      echo "The constrcut is running..." . '<br>'';
    }   
}
$employee = new Employee();
?>
```

*Second paragraph*

```
<?php
class Employee 
{
    protected $name;
    protected $title;

    function _construct()
    {
      echo "The constrcut is running..." . '<br>'';
    }   
}

class Manager extends Employee
{

    function __construct()
    {
      parent:: _construct();
      echo  "The Manager construct is running...";
    }
}
 $employee = new Manager();
?>
```

Comment: the constructor function should have two underscores as a prefix as does all other magic methods. Only the last constructor has the two underscores.

Comment: @andho ?? what's your meaning?

Comment: I see synthax errors in both codes, thats clearly not your original test. This should run once fixed and output just what its supposed to. Your problem must be somewhere else you are not telling.

Comment: It's pretty simple: You wrote `_construct()` instead of `__construct()`.

Comment: This. And `'<br>''` should be `'<br>'`.

Comment: @andho you said constructor function should have two underscores, then you said only last constructor has two underscores, can't get your point

Comment: `__construct()` is the name of the constructor function, `_construct()` (with one underscore) is wrong - change the function name in `Employee`.

Comment: Only the last constructor (the __construct function in Manager class) has two underscores (\_). That's the only that one is automatically called at the time of instantiation. The other constructors are never called automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace in the class `Employee`:

```
function _construct()
{
  echo "The constrcut is running..." . '<br>'';
}
```

With:

```
function __construct()
{
  echo "The constrcut is running..." . '<br>'';
}
```

Note the double underscores (`__`).

---

Also you have a syntax error here:

```
echo "The constrcut is running..." . '<br>'';
-------------------------------------------^ Why two 's?
```

Comment: Sorry but this question does not deserve an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. But just to give a helping hand.

Comment: sorry, that's my wrong typing